# How do I amalgamate different records into the same one in ms access

Tags: database, ms-access, record

I'm am trying to create a sports database (for a project) in access. And I am querying it to try create a list of games, see below.
[image: Query Result]

I'm and trying to 'shove' the top half down so that the home team and away team are in the same record, according to Team Number (these are renamed primary keys).
The query design looks like this.
[image]

Any solution would be greatly appreciated and I know I haven't given a lot of info so feel free to tell me to add more.

Comment: With ad-hoc tasks like that, I'll usually copy the data into Excel, do whatever I need to do, and then copy it back to Access.  The two are "made" for each other.  In this case I'd probably use Excel's "combine queries > merge" functionality, or else simple `IF` statements (depending on the specifics).  Do you know how to do that in Excel?

Comment: How are the records that should be merged related? Is Home Team Number always equal to Away Team Number?

Comment: Please show your original data.

Comment: Looks more like a game number than team number. Best to post the SQL statement of query, not image of the design view. Going by the limited dataset provided, could just do self-join query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following:

```
SELECT 
    tRounds_Home.Game_Number, 
    tRounds_Home.[TeamCode fk] AS [Home Team], 
    tRounds_Away.[TeamCode fk] AS [Away Team]
FROM 
    tRounds AS tRounds_Home 
    INNER JOIN tRounds AS tRounds_Away 
        ON tRounds_Home.Game_Number = tRounds_Away.Game_Number
WHERE
    tRounds_Home.[PlayingAs fk]="H"
    AND tRounds_Away.[PlayingAs fk])="A"
```

This presents the 'home' and 'away' teams from the two records per game_number.